# C# help split two byte word into bytes

Tags: c#, serial-port, arrays

Hello I am relatively new to C# programming and would appreciate some help, I am writing a program that communicates with a machine via RS232 and need to send a series of bytes to initiate coms. I have a two byte 16bit CRC word at the end of the packet that I think I need to split up into two bytes to fit into an array of bytes

```
// { <DLE> , <STX> , "G" , <DLE> , <ETX> , 16 BIT CRC CCITT split into two bytes}

byte[] byteToSend = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x02, 0x47, 0x10, 0x03, 0x421F };
```

When I convert 0x421F into binary and split it in half I get 0x42 and 0x1F
however the problem with the less significant byte 0x1F is when it is sent it is not padded with enough zeroes. I think it is just sent as <11111> instead of <00011111> as is required.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated
THanks
:)

Comment: Sending 0x1F will send both nibbles. Is it possible your problem is related to endianess? That is if does your machine expect a 16 bit value with the most significant byte first or the least? You have have to send 0x1F, 0x42 instead of 0x42, 0x1F

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] byteToSend = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x02, 0x47, 0x10, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x42 }
                                                               -----^
```

Or use BitConverter (which understands endianness):

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x421F);
```

Comment: even though the initializers are printed like that, i believe the question was how to split an arbitrary 16-bit value in code, not how to change a static initializer to do so.

Comment: Is it not 0x1F, 0x42 at the end instead of 0x42, 0x1F? It is probably a Little endian machine.

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes(0x421F)` would order them according to the endianness of the *controlling* machine, which may differ from the target's endianness.

Comment: On an intel machine (which is what it would be about 99.9 percent of the time) it is little endian.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] byteToSend = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x02, 0x47, 0x10, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x42 }
                                                               -----^
```

You need the bytes flipped *if* the target machine wants little-endian (likely if it's e.g. x86). If it's big-endian, use

```
byte[] byteToSend = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x02, 0x47, 0x10, 0x03, 0x42, 0x1F }
                                                               -----^
```

as Robert Harvey wrote.

(If you're not sure of the endianness, just try both.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this right?

```
        ushort value = 0x421F;
        byte value1 = (byte)(0x421F & 0xFF);
        byte value2 = (byte)(0x421F >> 8);
```